# $\frac{d}{d\theta}(\underline{r})$ from first principles

Tags: limits, derivatives, vectors

When I try to derive $\frac{d}{d\theta}(\underline{r})=R\underline{e_\theta}$ from first principles (limits and compound angle formulae) I get the following. By the time I've simplified and rearranged as much as I know how, it looks like some of the terms will diverge. Any thoughts? Please note: I'm not an expert at this, so any error(s) may be trivial.

\begin{align*} 
\frac{d}{d\theta}(\underline{r})
&=\lim_{\Delta\theta\rightarrow 0}\frac{\Delta(\underline{i}\cos\theta)+\Delta(\underline{j}\sin\theta)}{\Delta\theta}\tag{1}\\
&=\lim_{\Delta\theta\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{\Delta(\underline{i}\cos\theta)}{\Delta\theta}\right)+\lim_{\Delta\theta\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{\Delta(\underline{j}\sin\theta)}{\Delta\theta}\right)\tag{2}\\
&=\underline{i}\left[\lim_{\Delta\theta\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{\Delta\cos\theta}{\Delta\theta}\right)\right]+\underline{j}\left[\lim_{\Delta\theta\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{\Delta\sin\theta}{\Delta\theta}\right)\right]\tag{3}\\
&=\underline{i}\left[\lim_{\Delta\theta\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{\cos(\theta+\Delta\theta)-\cos\theta}{\Delta\theta}\right)\right]+\underline{j}\left[\lim_{\Delta\theta\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{\sin(\theta+\Delta\theta)-\sin\theta}{\Delta\theta}\right)\right]\tag{4}\\
&=\underline{i}\left[\lim_{\Delta\theta\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{\cos\theta\cos(\Delta\theta)-\sin\theta\sin(\Delta\theta)-\cos\theta}{\Delta\theta}\right)\right]+\underline{j}\left[\lim_{\Delta\theta\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{\sin\theta\cos(\Delta\theta)+\cos\theta\sin(\Delta\theta)-\sin\theta}{\Delta\theta}\right)\right]\tag{5}\\
&=\underline{i}\left[\lim_{\Delta\theta\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{\cos\theta\cos(\Delta\theta)}{\Delta\theta}-\frac{\sin\theta\sin(\Delta\theta)}{\Delta\theta}-\frac{\cos\theta}{\Delta\theta}\right)\right]+\underline{j}\left[\lim_{\Delta\theta\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{\sin\theta\cos(\Delta\theta)}{\Delta\theta}+\frac{\cos\theta\sin(\Delta\theta)}{\Delta\theta}-\frac{\sin\theta}{\Delta\theta}\right)\right]\tag{6}\\
&=\underline{i}\left[\lim_{\Delta\theta\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{\cos\theta\cos(\Delta\theta)}{\Delta\theta}-\sin\theta-\frac{\cos\theta}{\Delta\theta}\right)\right]+\underline{j}\left[\lim_{\Delta\theta\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{\sin\theta\cos(\Delta\theta)}{\Delta\theta}+\cos\theta-\frac{\sin\theta}{\Delta\theta}\right)\right]\tag{7}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

On reflection, I realise the divergent terms can be resolved using the standard result, $$\lim_{\Delta\theta\rightarrow 0}\frac{\cos(\Delta\theta)-1}{\Delta\theta}=0.$$